# Cert information - Firefox Add-on

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, ssl

Does anyone know a good add-on or method for Firefox to always show information about the used certificate, when visiting a HTTPS site?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: You might be interested in Perspectives and/or Certificate Patrol. They don't do exactly that, but they *do* warn you if the website's certificate has unexpectedly changed.

Answer (score 1):

[CertWatch](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/certificate-watch/) will do this - it'll popup a dialog showing the certificate used for the website

[image: CertWatch]

The first restart after installing the addon will take some time since it has to build the database of available certs - so don't think Firefox has crashed after installing it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an addon -  the address bar adds certificate info button at the starting of the address bar when you visit a https site. Click on it and it gives you all the info

Comment: I don't want to click every time I visit a HTTPS site.

Comment: i don't think you are going to find an addon that will give you a popup for the certificate info , because this is not something you are usually looking for , moreover firefox gives you a visual alert in the certificate button if the certificate cannot be validated , extra info usually warrants extra effort :)